# Facebook app on IOS won't update some threads

Tags: iphone, ios, facebook

Many threads that I visit frequently at some point stop updating. I get the notifications that someone has commented on the subject but when I click the link I can't see the latest changes. Even if I go back to the thread several weeks later I can't see anything after the point where the thread stopped from updating. As far as I know there is no app cache that can be cleaned or similar. How can I achieve to start updating those threads again? This doesn't happen with all threads just some. If I go into Safari I can see the changes after where the app stopped updating the thread.

My info: iPhone 5s, iOS 7.1
Facebook version 9.0.0.25.31

Thanks for suggestions!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sadly it's delete and reinstall.

I recommend Facebook's Paper app which behaves itself and provides a better interface IMHO https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/paper-stories-from-facebook/id794163692?mt=8

Comment: Delete and install solved it. But using the app two days I have again a tread that locked up. Terrible. I might try the Paper app.